# Freeradius remote database

Tags: centos7, freeradius

I am new in freeradius. I'm trying to connect remote mariadb database into freeradius. I have tried with my hosting ip address where in sql file but its not working. Is it possible to connect remote database in freeradius? if yes, how can I connect remote database.

Error Message : MySQL error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ip address'

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's possible.  That error means that your MySQL server isn't responding to requests from the RADIUS server.

Use `netstat -ln` on the MySQL server, and check for port 3306 to check it's actually started/listening.  If it is, verify firewalls are set to allow traffic on that port.